# Why is my lightning map disappearing after a split second?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community-builder, lightning-map

[image: image disappearing]I am trying to use a lightning map in communities to visualize some data and I started by using the example in the documentation to simulate what I need.

I want to have two options. Either show a list or a map with the list being the default. However when I click the map link(icon) the map shows for a split second and then list template is shown.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  >
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-around_medium slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-12">
            Displaying {num} of {total} projects
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-float_right">
                View results by:
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 ">
                <div class="slds-float_left" >
                    
                    <div class="slds-box  slds-box_xx-small box"> 
                        
                        <a href="#" onclick={viewList}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:list" alternative-text="list" title="List" class="my-icon"></lightning-icon></a>
                        <a href="#" onclick={viewMaps}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:location" alternative-text="location" title="Location" class="my-icon"></lightning-icon></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <template if:true={mapVisible}>
            <div class="slds-p-around_medium" >
                 <p >Maps content</p>
                 <lightning-map
                     map-markers={mapMarkers}>
                 </lightning-map>     
             </div>
         </template>
    <template if:false={mapVisible}>
        <p> Current list selection</p>
    </template>
   
        <p slot="footer"></p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

The Js..

```
       import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';


    export default class SearchResults extends LightningElement {
        num = 0;
        total = 0;
   
    mapVisible = false;
    
        mapMarkers = [
            {
                location: {
                    // Location Information
                    City: 'San Francisco',
                    Country: 'USA',
                    PostalCode: '94105',
                    State: 'CA',
                    Street: '50 Fremont St',
                },

                // For onmarkerselect
                value: 'SF1',

                // Extra info for tile in list & info window
                icon: 'standard:account',
                title: 'Julies Kitchen', // e.g. Account.Name
                description: 'This is a long description',
            },
            {
                location: {
                    // Location Information
                    City: 'San Francisco',
                    Country: 'USA',
                    PostalCode: '94105',
                    State: 'CA',
                    Street: '30 Fremont St.',
                },

                // For onmarkerselect
                value: 'SF2',

                // Extra info for tile in list
                icon: 'standard:account',
                title: 'Tender Greens', // e.g. Account.Name
            },
        ];

        selectedMarkerValue = 'SF1';


    viewList(){
        console.log('View List');
       this.mapVisible = false;
        
    }
    
        viewMaps(){
            console.log('Show Maps');
            this.mapVisible = true;
            
        console.log('Visible ' + this.mapVisible);
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe check location on your browser? I set up your code and with no modifications, it works fine. Could use a format though...

Comment: That's interesting. I have tried with Firefox and it is showing after clicking twice! So strange. I did not change any location settings. In chrome, still disappearing on click. I allowed in the settings but still behaving the same way. Thanks Caspar for taking the time to help I really appreciate.

Comment: I tried in chrome too. I see you have some other code/markup - maybe try what I did and just display this component.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was that the page was refreshing. The reason was that I had used a href="#". To make the link not refresh on click I changed to..

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick={viewMap}>  <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:list" alternative-text="list" title="List" class="my-icon" ></lightning-icon></a>
```